# jQuery - show div content on button click (modal style)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

What I am aiming for is to have all the divs hidden (via css class) and then show them in a modal style popup (again done via css). For instance:

```
<a href="" id="speclinkOpen">Show Spec</a>
<div class="speclink">   
    <h1>This is spec 1</h1>
    <a id="speclinkClose">Close</a>    
</div>

<a href="" id="speclinkOpen">Show Spec</a>
<div class="speclink">   
    <h1>This is spec 2</h1>
    <a id="speclinkClose">Close</a>    
</div>
```

the content in the divs (class of speclink) are hidden. when they press the button (id speclinkOpen) I want it to show the relevant content so "This is spec 1" if the top button is clicked or "this is spec 2 if the bottom button is clicked.

I know I will need to use on.click THIS as opposed to the actual class name but not entirely sure how i go about it..could anyone shed some light on it for me?

Essentially the jQuery would show the div content in an overlay style but how does it know which div content to load based on which button was pressed as im using the same class name? Naming each differently isnt an option as i have so many but perhaps i'm going about the problem totally the wrong way? Thanks John.

Comment: There are hundreds of plugins which do this. Is there a reason you can't use one? Is this just a personal project to learn jQuery?

Comment: Note: ID of an element must be unique.... there are multiple elements with same ID in your sample code.... use class attribute to group similar elements

Comment: personal project to learn..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/%E2%80%8E).

You could do something like in your html:

```
<a href="#" class="speclinkOpen" data-div="div1">Show Spec</a>
<div class="speclink" id="div1">   
    <h1>This is spec 1</h1>
    <a id="speclinkClose1">Close</a>    
</div>

<a href="#" class="speclinkOpen" data-div="div2">Show Spec</a>
<div class="speclink" id="div2">   
    <h1>This is spec 2</h1>
    <a id="speclinkClose2">Close</a>    
</div>
```

And in jQuery script:

```
$(function(){
    $('img.speclinkOpen').on('click', function(){
       var id = $(this).data('div'); // take the id to "highlight"
       $('#' + id).addClass('modal'); // do whatever you want in with class or .css()
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

If you can't use data attributes because you cannot assign id attribute uniquely to your divs:

```
$(function(){
    $('img.speclinkOpen').on('click', function(){
       $(this).next('div.speclink').addClass('modal'); // do whatever you want in with class or .css()
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem I have is that the are hundreds which would need individual unique data attributes..

Comment: If they are created dynamically, just add a counter and create the ids automatically. Otherwhise, you could use .next() selector from jQuery. Check my update.

Comment: sorry can i ask for more guidance here? I created the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/P5mkt/1/ but if you click the first show spec it shows fine, then click the next show spec it shows fine BUT if you then click back on the first one again it doesnt change back?

Comment: also when i use the code that works in that jsfiddle on an actual page nothing happens when i click the show spec links...

Comment: With .css('display', 'block') you only show the div, but you also need to hide the first one when you show the second one because in your case the first div is shown below the second.

Comment: No problem, just say it was useful! :)